# Spring cloud config client for SSL protected config server on Pivotal instance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring cloud config application deployed on a PAAS (Cloud foundry) instance. While consuming the properties from my client application, deployed on the same PAAS instance, I get an SSL exception, as Pivotal needs an SSL certificate to be passed from my client application.
Now I have tried a couple of ways to get around this -

1. Tried using "cloudfoundry-certificate-truster" with cf_target set -> This works, properties are loaded fine but my application fails to start, and keeps crashing without any error.
2. Tried keeping a jks file in src/main/resources with the required certificate, but somehow the deployed application is not referring to it, and still fails with the certificate error. I had loaded the jks file from main method, and had put sysouts before and after context loads with the location to the jks file, the sysouts are consistent but don't work :(
   Note - I have another application which is not consuming from my cloud config server, and the truststore approach works there, if I pass the jvm property in post-construct.
   The tricky part with a cloud config client is that Properties are binded/loaded before context load and hence I am forced to set the truststore from main method.

So, I want to know if anyone has been able to get this thing work, and also if I can somehow load these properties "lazily", say after context load. I came across spring.cloud.config.enabled=false, to disable the auto-load but couldn;t find much information - is it the right way to go ?

Answer (score 0):

> Tried using "cloudfoundry-certificate-truster" with cf_target set -> This works, properties are loaded fine but my application fails to start, and keeps crashing without any error.

This is the best approach when using self-signed certificates with CF.

Try running `cf events APP_NAME` to see if that gives any clues why the app is crashing. It's possible you aren't giving the container enough memory for the app to successfully start.

Comment: cf apps produces following -

2016-09-07T06:30:39.00+0530   app.crash          myApp     index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: 2 error(s) occurred:

* 1 error(s) occurred:

* Exited with status 1
* 1 error(s)   occurred:

I checked in console, and found that ample of memory was free, moreover, without the truster, my app startups without any error, surely the truster itself must not be consuming so much of memory (or could it ?)

Comment: I am wary of using the truster approach also because I have several 3rd party apps which use SSL, and I couldn't find how to have an array of cf_targets to fetch the certificate for each ..